# Sending folder over network in Java

Tags: java, sockets, send

Is there a builtin method that can send a folder over a network? Have not found any!

Comment: A folder is an ideal, not a tangible file in and of itself.  There are many files inside of a folder, and the many files are what you would have to transfer over.  There are plenty of libraries that exist for that.

Comment: Basically, [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/). The question show little intuitive on your part to investigate the problem.

Comment: @MadProgrammer I know that I can iterate over each entry in folder and send file or recurse if it's another folder..Just asking if sending a folder can be done by other means..

Answer (score 3):

No there is not a builtin method to do this.

But there are other means, some comes into thoughts :

- Send the File object to a remote java object via RMI using a tool like [RMIIO](http://openhms.sourceforge.net/rmiio/)
- Zip the folder and upload it to a remote host using HTTP or FTP
- Or you can even upload the zipped folder to a raw socket port